# Problems Loading Static Files into Django Dev Environment

Tags: django, django-static

I am trying to load static files into my Django project and it just isn't working.

Inside my settings.py file I have defined the below:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
```

This is a screenshot around how my project structure is setup:

[image]

When the template is rendered only the text shows up - no image. HTML below to show the syntax behind static file loading:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load static %}
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <img src="{% static 'test.png' %}" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic` to populate your static folder.

Also, during development you can use the following in your main `urls.py` to serve your static files (from django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

You must have `STATIC_ROOT` configured in `settings.py`.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem. Not sure how this would, as it would just collect all the static data (for production deployment?)

Comment: Did you already try it? Because by default you urlconf will not point to you development static files (Did you edit your `urls.py` to allow this?). Also "production deployment" depends on you. If you say it's a folder in the same server it will be, but django will look there when trying to resolve the file locations.

Comment: Edited to include urlconf to a serve static files in development.